# How to sort Parallel Arrays from highest to lowest

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to sort out the input which is name followed by the grades, I only want to sort out the grades

Sample input:

```
3 (Scanner limit) 
Hussain
 70
Omer
 60
User
 92
```

Sample Output:

```
User
 92
Hussain
 70
Omer
 60
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Sortingofgrades{
 public static void main(String []args){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
     int num = keyboard.nextInt();
     String name[] = new String [num];
     int grade[] = new int [num];
        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++){
                name[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
                grade[x] = keyboard.nextInt();
                Arrays.sort(grade);
                    System.out.println(name[x]+grade[x]);
            }
        }
     
 }
```

This code does not work as I get an `mismatchedexception` error after i type the limit

for instance:

```
3
mismatchedexception
```

Comment: Why are you using parallel arrays? And what's your question? Is there a problem with your code? Please be more specific.

Comment: You need a data structure for holding the name, score combination

Answer (score 1):

If you like to sort your pairs based on grades, you can use `SortedMap` which is sorted by keys, and store your grades as key.

```
    SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
        // get name and grade values
        map.put(grade, name);
    }
```

`TreeMap` is implemented based on red-black tree structure, and it is ordered by the key. When you print out your pairs, it will be sorted based on grade, so you don't need to worry about sorting your values.